# coerce ngCMatrix as dgCMatrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm using sparseMatrix to convert group-affiliation data to a social graph (two-mode to one-mode, [as explained here](http://web.stanford.edu/~messing/Affiliation%20Data.html)), but am not sure: how to coerce a sparse pattern matrix object to a sparse integer matrix?

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
dt <- data.table(person = c('Sam','Sam','Sam','Greg','Tom','Tom','Tom','Mary','Mary'), 
                 group = c('a','b','e','a','b','c','d','b','d'))

# non-sparse, desirable output
M <- as.matrix(table(dt))
M %*% t(M)

# sparse, binary instead of integer 
rows <- sort(unique(dt$person))
cols <- sort(unique(dt$group))
dimnamesM <- list(person = rows, groups = cols)
sprsM <- sparseMatrix(i = match(dt$person, rows), 
                      j = match(dt$group, cols), dimnames = dimnamesM)
sprsM %*% t(sprsM)
```

Comment: You could post it as an answer, as it could be useful for other users to know this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `sprsM <- as(sprsM, "dgCMatrix")` does it. For more details see [here](http://www.inside-r.org/node/41352)

```
sprsM <- sparseMatrix(i = match(dt$person, rows), 
                      j = match(dt$group, cols), dimnames = dimnamesM)
sprsM
# 4 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
#       groups
# person a b c d e
#   Greg | . . . .
#   Mary . | . | .
#   Sam  | | . . |
#   Tom  . | | | .

class(sprsM)
# [1] "ngCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"

sprsM <- as(sprsM, "dgCMatrix")
sprsM
# 4 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#       groups
# person a b c d e
#   Greg 1 . . . .
#   Mary . 1 . 1 .
#   Sam  1 1 . . 1
#   Tom  . 1 1 1 .

class(sprsM)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"
```

Comment: This is off the question, but useful to note that `summary (object = "sparseMatrix")` is a method that returns an object of S3 class "sparseSummary" which is basically a data.frame with columns (i,j,x)